API calls don't work after installing TailwindCSS
I just finished a perfectly working 'Google Drive' clone as a personal project. It uses cloudinary API and Prisma ORM.
Everything worked perfectly fine until I decided to install TailwindCSS and now the calls don't work anymore.
For example this line now results always in Error:
        const result = await cloudinary.api.resource(publicId, { resource_type: resourceType });


or this prisma query also results always in error, even though if I copy-paste it into another .js file it works perfectly fine.
const folder = await prisma.folder.findUnique({
        where: { id: req.params.id },
        include: { children: true, files: true }
    });


    if (!folder) {
        throw Error('Folder not found');
    }


    res.render('folder', { folder });

I'm losing my mind, does someone know why does this happen?
Here is my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./views/**/*.{html,js,ejs}",
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          "50": "#eff6ff",
          "100": "#dbeafe",
          "200": "#bfdbfe",
          "300": "#93c5fd",
          "400": "#60a5fa",
          "500": "#3b82f6",
          "600": "#2563eb",
          "700": "#1d4ed8",
          "800": "#1e40af",
          "900": "#1e3a8a",
          "950": "#172554"
        }
      },
      fontFamily: {
        'body': [
          'Inter',
          'ui-sans-serif',
          'system-ui',
          '-apple-system',
          'system-ui',
          'Segoe UI',
          'Roboto',
          'Helvetica Neue',
          'Arial',
          'Noto Sans',
          'sans-serif',
          'Apple Color Emoji',
          'Segoe UI Emoji',
          'Segoe UI Symbol',
          'Noto Color Emoji'
        ],
        'sans': [
          'Inter',
          'ui-sans-serif',
          'system-ui',
          '-apple-system',
          'system-ui',
          'Segoe UI',
          'Roboto',
          'Helvetica Neue',
          'Arial',
          'Noto Sans',
          'sans-serif',
          'Apple Color Emoji',
          'Segoe UI Emoji',
          'Segoe UI Symbol',
          'Noto Color Emoji'
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}


